# How to slice the same range of hours from each day for month of data?

Tags: python, pandas

As the title describes, I'm trying to slice the same range of hours from each day in a month long dataset stored in a pandas dataframe.  The data is recorded at odd intervals ranging from 13-16 seconds.

i.e. Slice out 00:00:00 - 06:00:00 for every day in the dataset.

Data's index is a pandas datetime type recorded as *2019-04-15T03:00:00Z*.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the time from the `datetime` index into another column and filter on that - something along the lines of;

```
import datetime

start_time = datetime.time(0,0,0)
end_time = datetime.time(6,0,0)

df['time'] = df.index.dt.time

df = df[ (df['time'] > start_time) & (df['time'] < end_time) ]
```